# curvilinear coordinates - effects of choice of coordinate system for $\mathbf{r}$ on basis vectors

Tags: differential-geometry, vector-analysis, coordinate-systems, curvilinear-coordinates

I'm taking the course *Mathematics for Physicists* this semester, and in the last week, we talked about curvilinear coordinate systems.
we began the discussion by defining coordinate curves (curves in which only one coordinate changes and the others are constant). We talked about the tangents to these curves, which would give us the basis vectors of the curved coordinate system (at least locally).
we found those basis vectors by taking the partial derivative of the position vector **r**, with respect to the changing coordinate, i.e. $\frac{\partial \mathbf{r}}{\partial q_i}$.

It would be great if someone could clarify in which coordinate system we are looking at $\mathbf r$. For example, if we take the transformation of cartesian coordinates to cylindrical, we get that $\mathbf r$ is $\mathbf{r}= (x,y,z)$ and if we take the partial derivative with respect to $r$ (the radius), we would get $\hat {r}= \cos(\theta)\hat {x} + \sin(\theta)\hat {y}$, but if we would take $\mathbf r$ to be in cylindrical $\mathbf{r}= r\hat {r} + z\hat {z}$, which partial derivative with respect to $r$ is just $\hat {r}$, which is not surprising.

How does the choice of representation of the position vector (e.g., Cartesian coordinates vs. general coordinates) influence the resulting basis vectors obtained by taking partial derivatives?

So, in which coordinates system should I look at $\mathbf r$? if I take the transformation from coordinate system $A$ to $B$, should I look at the representation of $\mathbf r$ in $A$ and take the partials with respect to the coordinates in $B$?

Could you provide an explanation or example that highlights the impact of different coordinate systems on basis vectors and partial derivatives? Are there any general principles or rules that govern the transformation of basis vectors and partial derivatives when switching between coordinate systems?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're looking at coordinate curves, i.e curves where only one coordinate is changing, then you can think of such a curve as a parameterized curve with the parameter being that one changing coordinate. So for example, the coordinate curve in 3d given by $(x,y_0,z_0)$ where only $x$ varies but $y_0$ and $z_0$ are fixed can be represented as the parameterized curve $r(t) = (t,y_0,z_0)$. Equivalently, the tangent is defined to be $\frac{dr}{dt}$, blah blah blah. Now in general, for a non-coordinate curve, we first consider a parameterization
$$r(t) = (x(t),y(t),z(t))$$
And so the derivative is still in terms of the parameter, not the coordinate.
That means the tangent is still $\frac{dr}{dt}$. The unit tangent is the normalized tangent, the normal is the the derivative of the unit tangent and so on. So derivative being with respect to coordinates is just a special case of the coordinates being the parameter. Does that make sense?